# How to select column names and tables of an SQL using regex?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, regex

I have an SQL string that looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    USER."ID", USER."NAME", USER."BIRTH",USER."GENDER",
    PACKAGE."type"
    PACKAGE."code"
FROM
    "DBNAME"."USER" USER,
    "DBNAME2"."PACKAGE" PACKAGE
WHERE
    USER."PACKAGE_ID" = PACKAGE."ID"
ORDER BY
    USER."NAME";
```

How should I write my regular expression in C# to extract all the column names between the SELECT and FROM keywords, and then the table names in the FROM clause?

The expected output should find these so that I can put them into `List` to loop through:

ColumnsList:

```
USER."ID"
USER."NAME"
USER."BIRTH"
USER."GENDER"
PACKAGE."type"
PACKAGE."code"
```

TablesList:

```
"DBNAME"."USER" USER
"DBNAME2"."PACKAGE" PACKAGE
```

Comment: Can you show an example of desired output?

Comment: Using a lexer is easier than regex for parsing SQL.

Comment: regex is the most (mis)used tool for this type of things. you need a parser. @hjpotter92's lexer may not be sufficient. checkout this impl **[here at codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32524/SQL-Parser)**. this may be a bit more for your current needs, but will scale well with future demands. queries *will* grow complex and you may need more than column and table names.

Comment: @inquisitive unfortunately, the implementation at codeproject doesn't support the select clause at this time. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this Regex will get the column and table name:

```
  (?is)SELECT(.*?)(?<!\w*")FROM(?!\w*?")(.*?)(?=WHERE|ORDER|$)
```

- Group[1] :　column
- Group[2] : table name

Code Samples:

```
string sql=@"SELECT
    USER.""ID"", USER.""NAME"", USER.""BIRTH"",USER.""GENDER"",
    PACKAGE.""type""
    PACKAGE.""code""
FROM
    ""DBNAME"".""USER"" USER,
    ""DBNAME2"".""PACKAGE"" PACKAGE
WHERE
    USER.""PACKAGE_ID"" = PACKAGE.""ID""
ORDER BY
    USER.""NAME"";";

    var reg=new Regex(@"(?is)SELECT(.*?)(?<!\w*"")FROM(?!\w*?"")(.*?)(?=WHERE|ORDER|$)");
    var colunms=reg.Match(sql).Groups[1].Value.Split(new char[]{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var tables=reg.Match(sql).Groups[2].Value.Split(new char[]{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Thanks! This one worked pretty well. Except that I realise for SQLs that have column names with the word "FROM" in it will cause it extract wrongly. Say `Select USER."FROM_COUNTRY"...`, this will cause the regex to break.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. But it seems like it still doesn't work. I have a query that is like `select USER."TRAVEL_FROM_COUNTRY"...` the regex will stop right after `TRAVEL_` due to the FROM keyword.

Comment: @Carven test `USER."TRAVEL_FROM_COUNTRY"` with my regex, it works well. you can list your test sql ,then I can debug my regex code.

Comment: ohh.. I realised what happened. In a few of the SQL files I have, they may not have the quotes around them. So, they look like `USER.TRAVEL_FROM_COUNTRY` or `USER.FROM_COUNTRY`. This will cause the problem. Those with the quotes are okay, but not those without the quotes. How can I resolve this?

Comment: @Carven You should list all your ruels when you ask question. here is the last update: `(?is)SELECT(.*?)(?<!\w*["_])FROM(?!\w*?["_])(.*?)(?=WHERE|ORDER|$)`