# Parse TSQL select query and return column expressions

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, t-sql

I am looking for a function or some TSQL parser in c# where TSQL select query will be an input parameter and output of that function will be a table containing all the fields and their complex expressions written on that select query. Had already found some solution on ggl but those are limited to parse SQL query and extract column's name and table(s) being used.

Input TSQL:

@sql = 'Select case when 1=1 then 'Equal' else 'Not Equal' end as [FirstColumn], ISNULL(somefield) as [SecondColumn], '3rd field' as [ThirdColumn], someTable.anotherColumn from someTable'

Desired Output table:

[image]

Note - I have used small query here for example but in actual there is a big select TSQL query having complex sql logics written.

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: By regular expression, you can solve your problem refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299032/how-to-select-column-names-and-tables-of-an-sql-using-regex)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlQuery method from DbSet:

```
var result = await dbContext.Entities.SqlQuery("....").ToListAsync();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbSet_1_SqlQuery_System_String_System_Object___

Comment: thanks for your quick response... but unfortunately I don't have any table schema using which I can generate/use dbContext methods. I just have a big select query as a plain string with no such database schema available.

Comment: In such case from my experience you have 2 options: you can define proper classes yourself or I would recommend using ADO .NET directly without any ORM as in case you have no model classes orm will bring you no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlParser '[Carbunql](https://github.com/mk3008/Carbunql)'.

```cs
using Carbunql;

//Parse the select query into an object
var sq = new SelectQuery(@"Select 
case when 1=1 then 'Equal' else 'Not Equal' end as [FirstColumn],
ISNULL(somefield) as [SecondColumn], '3rd field' as [ThirdColumn],
someTable.anotherColumn
from someTable");

//get select clause element
sq.SelectClause!.Items.ForEach(item =>
{
    //get the name
    Console.Write("Name : " + item.Alias);
    
    //get the value without name
    Console.Write(", Value : " + item.Value.ToOneLineCommand().CommandText);

    //get expression
    Console.Write(", Expression : " + item.ToOneLineCommand().CommandText);

    Console.WriteLine();
});
```

results

```
Name : [FirstColumn], Value : case when 1 = 1 then 'Equal' else 'Not Equal' end, Expression : case when 1 = 1 then 'Equal' else 'Not Equal' end as [FirstColumn]
Name : [SecondColumn], Value : ISNULL(somefield), Expression : ISNULL(somefield) as [SecondColumn]
Name : [ThirdColumn], Value : '3rd field', Expression : '3rd field' as [ThirdColumn]
Name : anotherColumn, Value : someTable.anotherColumn, Expression : someTable.anotherColumn
```